# Nested while loop not executing

Tags: perl, debugging, loops

I have the following code, the only problem is that when the code gets to the nested while loop it skips it, I'm assuming the condition is not being met, but can anyone see something I amy have done wrong? I have verified that all the flags that I give to the script are correct and that the job_name is what I think it should be.

```
open $alOut,
     "/home/usr/bin/test.pl -j EW-% -j RA-% -l 0 | grep `date \"+%m/%d/%Y\"` | sort -k 3,3|";
while (<$alOut>) {
    chomp;
    my ($job_name, $date, $start_time, $end_time, $duration,
        $state, $return, $expected_end_time) = split(/\s+/, $_);

    # Go to next iteration if jobname is EW-INTERNAL-AUTOSYS,
    # EW-INTERNAL-DB-LONGQUERY-ALERT, EW-INTERNAL-DB-LONGQUERY-ALERT,
    # EW-CIIM-ADJ-TRIGGER, or EW-S140-ADJ-TRIGGER
    if (($job_name eq "EW-INTERNAL-AUTOSYS") ||
        ($job_name eq "EW-INTERNAL-DB-LONGQUERY-ALERT") ||
        ($job_name eq "EW-INTERNAL-SYSUP") ||
        ($job_name eq "EW-CIIM-ADJ-TRIGGER") ||
        ($job_name eq "EW-S140-ADJ-TRIGGER"))
        {
            next;
        }

    #Expected Start Time
    open $alOut2,
         "/home/usr/bin/test.pl -j $job_name -q -l 0 | grep -E `condition:|start_times:`";
    while (<$alOut2>) { .... }
}
```

Comment: You should test if there are errors on open.

Comment: You might want to use `while(defined(my $line1 = <$alOut>))` and `while(defined(my $line2 = <$alOut2>))` here, otherwise you'll be using `$_` for two different things in the same scope and that'll probably cause some confusion sooner or later.

Comment: That first comment in your code is a classical example for "how not to comment code".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check for errors from `open`:

```
open $fh, ... or die "Can't open: $!";
```

And in this grep:

```
grep `condition:|start_times:`
```

you probably want regular single quotes (`'`), not backticks, the shell is going to try to run a command called `condition:`. And I think you are missing a final `|` in that command.

Answer (score 3):

You should always check the value returned by `open`:

```
open "...whatever..." or die "Can't open: $!";
```

That will probably tell you all you need to know, but offhand, I can see two problems:

1. The second open isn't terminated by a `|` character.
2. The backticks after the grep should be apostrophes.